# on click disable the input fields in a rails app

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have these two radio buttons and three input fields in my table for my rails app.

```
<td>
  <input type="radio"  onclick="make_enable('<%=uniqid%>')"  value="cheque" name="expense[<%=uniqid%>][cheque_cash]" id="expense_cheque_cash<%=uniqid%>" >
</td>

<td>
  <input type="radio"  onclick="make_enable('<%=uniqid%>')"  value="cheque" name="expense[<%=uniqid%>][chq_no]" id="expense_cheque_no<%=uniqid%>" >
</td>

<td>
  <input disabled='disabled'  type="number" name="expense[<%=uniqid%>][bank_name]" id="expense_bank_name<%=uniqid%>" >
</td>

<td>
  <input type="text" disabled='disabled' name="expense[<%=uniqid%>][comments]" id="expense_comments<%=uniqid%>" >
</td>

 <td>
  <input type="text" disabled='disabled' name="expense[<%=uniqid%>][cheque_no]" id="expense_cheque_no<%=uniqid%>" >
 </td>
```

On click of one of the radio button, I am trying to enable to three by default disabled buttons.

Here's the script I am using.

```
    function make_disabled(uniqid)
     {
      $("#expense_chq_no"+uniqid).val('');
      $("#expense_chq_no"+uniqid).attr('disabled','disabled');

      $("#expense_bank_name"+uniqid).val('');
      $("#expense_bank_name"+uniqid).attr('disabled','disabled');

      $("#expense_comments"+uniqid).val('');
      $("#expense_comments"+uniqid).attr('disabled','disabled'); 
    }

   function make_enable(uniqid)
    {
      $("#expense_chq_no"+uniqid).removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#expense_bank_name"+uniqid).removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#expense_comments"+uniqid).removeAttr('disabled'); 
    }
```

I am not able to rectify the problem here. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try with `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` like `.prop('disabled',true)`